# What is the Google Map zoom algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, google-maps

I'm working on a map zoom algorithm which change the area (part of the map visible) coordinates on click.

For example, at the beginning, the area has this coordinates :

- (0, 0) for the corner upper left
- (100, 100) for the corner lower right
- (100, 100) for the center of the area

And when the user clicks somewhere in the area, at a (x, y) coordinate, I say that the new coordinates for the area are :

- (x-(100-0)/3, y-(100-0)/3) for the corner upper left
- (x+(100-0)/3, y+(100-0)/3) for the corner upper right
- (x, y) for the center of the area

The problem is that algorithm is not really powerful because when the user clicks somewhere, the point which is under the mouse moves to the middle of the area.

So I would like to have an idea of the algorithm used in Google Maps to change the area coordinates because this algorithm is pretty good : when the user clicks somewhere, the point which is under the mouse stays under the mouse, but the rest of area around is zoomed.

Somebody has an idea of how Google does ?

Comment: Google does a combination of simple magnification and replacement with more-detailed maps when you zoom in far enough that their details are meaningful. What do you need to know beyond that?

Comment: @keshlam Thanks. But it's not exactly what I wanted to know. I'm going to edit my question, to be more specific.

Comment: More specific is always better. "Mindreading costs extra."

Comment: What do you mean by "not really powerful"? What else do you _THINK_ it could or should do? What else do you think Google is doing?

Comment: @keshlam I edited again my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lets say you have rectangle `windowArea` which holds drawing area coordinates(i.e web browser window area in pixels), for example if you are drawing map on the whole screen and the top left corner has coordinates (0, 0) then that rectangle will have values:

```
windowArea.top = 0;
windowArea.left = 0;
windowArea.right = maxWindowWidth;
windowArea.bottom = maxWindowHeight;
```

You also need to know visible map fragment, that will be longitude and latitude ranges, for example:

```
mapArea.top = 8.00; //lat
mapArea.left = 51.00; //lng
mapArea.right = 12.00; //lat
mapArea.bottom = 54.00; //lng
```

When zooming recalculate mapArea:

```
mapArea.left = mapClickPoint.x - (windowClickPoint.x- windowArea.left) * (newMapWidth / windowArea.width());
mapArea.top = mapClickPoint.y - (windowArea.bottom - windowClickPoint.y) * (newMapHeight / windowArea.height());
mapArea.right = mapArea.left + newWidth;
mapArea.bottom = mapArea.top + newHeight;
```

`mapClickPoint` holds map coordinates under mouse pointer(longitude, latitude).
`windowClickPoint` holds window coordinates under mouse pointer(pixels).
`newMapHeight` and `newMapWidth` hold new ranges of visible map fragment after zoom:

```
newMapWidth = zoomFactor * mapArea.width;//lets say that zoomFactor = <1.0, maxZoomFactor>
newMapHeight = zoomFactor * mapArea.height;
```

When you have new `mapArea` values you need to stretch it to cover whole `windowArea`, that means `mapArea.top/left` should be drawn at `windowArea.top/left` and `mapArea.right/bottom` should be drawn at `windowArea.right/bottom`.

I am not sure if google maps use the same algorithms, it gives similar results and it is pretty versatile but you need to know window coordinates and some kind of coordinates for visible part of object that will be zoomed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

Let us state the problem in 1 dimension, with the input (left, right, clickx, ratio)
So basically, you want to have the ratio to the click from the left and to the right to be the same:

```
Left'-clickx    right'-clickx
------------- = --------------
 left-clickx     right-clickx
```

and furthermore, the window is reduced, so:

```
right'-left'   
------------ = ratio
 right-left
```

Therefore, the solution is:

```
left'  = ratio*(left -clickx)+clickx
right' = ratio*(right-clickx)+clickx
```

And you can do the same for the other dimensions.

Comment: Hi Mikaël, I have just seen now that you answered to my questions I asked three years ago! I asked this question for Reflex4you because I wanted to reproduce the zoom algorithm for zooming into Reflex.